# Using try-with-resources with things that are not "resources"

Tags: java, coding-style, try-with-resources

I have a continuously running service that I want stopped cleanly if it hits an exception. This fits well with the try with resources paradigm but it's not really a resource that needs to be "closed".

To clarify based on comments, my code looks something like this

```
class Service {
  Resource resource;
  State state;
  boolean keepRunning = false;

  void start() {
     keepRunning = true;
     resource = new Resource()
     new Thread(() -> {
            while(keepRunning) {
                Data data = resources.pull();
                state.update(data);
                ... // Do stuff with state
            }
        }).start();
  }
  void stop() {
    keepRunning = false;
  }
}

class Main {
   void run() {
        Service service = new Service();
        service.start();
   }
}
```

Is there a pattern that lets me use the syntactic sugar that try-with-resources provides while still not abusing try-with-resources with things that are not resources?

Comment: This is unclear.  What, specifically, do you mean by a "service"?  And what does "stop cleanly" involve?

Comment: It's mostly just a continuously running while loop that runs a periodic task. This task internally spawns a thread that keeps updating itself with latest data from a resource. Stop involves breaking out of the loop and closing the resource.

Comment: In order to use try with resources, you just need to implement `Closable`. But you don't need to have anything in the close method

Comment: @cricket I understand that. What I'm trying to understand is if it okay to use try with resources for things that are not resources but do fit that paradigm

Comment: @cricket_007 `AutoCloseable`

Comment: @shmosel actually closeable works as well

Comment: @Glyde If it is a service I'm not entirely sure, how you would use try with resources. To clean up after the the JVM closes you can use a shutdown hook. Also you can use try..finally in your thread (and main) to execute some code on unexpected exception. If the JVM crashes, there are usually not many things you can do, the shutdown hook may or may not run depending on how it crashed.

Comment: `Closeable` is a subclass of `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with it? Can you show some examples. Just from your description it is not clear whether this construct will be helpful or not.

Comment: @Zabuza I added some sample code. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is totally okay to use **try-with-resources** with anything you want. The requirement is that it implements the interface `AutoCloseable` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)). With that interface you will need to implement a `close` method, which then is called by the **try-with-resources** construct.

That is why this interface is there, you are allowed to implement it for your own classes.

For example if you have a service that needs to be probably shut down, also in error case, you may use `AutoCloseable` and implement the `close` method probably.

However it's **meaningless** and will **confuse readers** of your program if you make something `AutoCloseable` where there is totally **no intuition** what **close** means on this object. In such cases you should probably look for other constructs.

---

It's a bit like implementing `Iterable` such that you can use the *enhanced for loop* like:

```
for (Item item : myObject) {
    ...
}
```

You may do it, if it **makes sense**. Otherwise it will confuse people.

Comment: That's exactly my concern. I like the syntactic sugar that try with resources provides and me not having to do the error handling. However, close() makes no sense in this context, and stop() is what makes sense

Comment: Well then don't use it. It's really opinion based in that case. I doubt people here will be able to help you. Personally I wouldn't use it, but I don't like the construct that much anyway.

Comment: Maybe my question should be this then: Is there a way/pattern to use try-with-resources in this case in a way that makes sense? Something like having a ephemeral resource that is used by the service?

Comment: @Glyde It sounds like what you're looking for is dependency injection, not so much lifecycle management

Comment: @cricket How would dependency injection help me start and stop my service cleanly ?

Comment: @Glyde You've not really specified under which conditions your service stops, and if there's nothing to "close", then there's nothing worth "cleaning stopping"

Comment: That seems fair. I close on exceptions inside the service.